"FATAL: role " postgres" does not exist" When running postgres docker image
I'm working on a app where I use a postgres database. I run everything in containers using docker-compose.
My compose file looks like this:
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    ... # Backend stuff, runs fine
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    ... #Frontend stuff, runs fine
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*********** #This is a proper password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD","pg_isready", "-d", "postgres", "-h", "localhost", "-p 5432", "-U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s

Everything works and runs fine, however, my database container constantly prints out this error message:
FATAL:  role " postgres" does not exist
I do not specify any users, so from my understanding the default role "postgres" should be created when building the image.
I have also seen many people experiencing this problem if they have other postgres databases running on their system, this is not the case for me.
PS.
My backend is written in python using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy with psycopg.
And it connects to the database using the URL 'postgresql+psycopg://postgres:DBPASSWORD@db:5432'

Try removing the single apostrophe (') in volumes:. Did you create the docker-volume db?

The thing I notice is the space before 'postgres' in your error message. That looks weird. Is your program trying to connect using " postgres"  with a space?

I also thought that was weird. As far as I can see nothing tries to connect to it with " postgres".  I connect to it using this database url "'postgresql+psycopg://postgres:dbpassword@db:5432'"

@kometen I removed them, however, it did not help this situation.

Use colon (:) as separator in POSTGRES_PASSWORD, not equal (=), like POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd.

You also need to specify the volume as it's own section, same level as services. Like volumes:   db:

I think the configuration of the database container is fine, except that you've misspelled postgressql with an extra s in the bind mount target.  @HansKilian's suggestion seems more likely.  How are you configuring the database client?  You show an SQLAlchemy URL; is that hard-coded, or constructed in code, or injected from environment variables?

@kometen It's currently hardcoded just as i've written here.


Docker networking might not resolve localhost to the correct container IP. For that case, remove localhost and add db. With this change, -h db tells PostgreSQL to connect to the service named db defined in your compose file.

version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    ... # Backend stuff, runs fine
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    ... #Frontend stuff, runs fine
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data     
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*********** #This is a proper password
    healthcheck:
      test: 
        [
          "CMD",
          "pg_isready",
          "-d",
          "postgres",
          "-h",
          "db", # Changed "localhost" to "db"
          "-p 5432",
          "-U postgres",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
volumes:
  db-data:


Setting all variables is not necassary as it uses the default postgres_user which is postgres and the default db name which is also postgres. For my application right now I prefer using a bind mount.
However, it seems to be the networking under the healthcheck that is the problem. Changing it to db instead of localhost seems to have solved my issue. I would very much like to know why though, as I would expect a no response error and for the backend service never to be started.

Thank you for your feedback. I'm delighted the issue is resolved and editing the answer according to your feedback.
Using  service name db allows the healthcheck command to correctly locate the PostgreSQL database container. This provides your app or service to connect to the specific container running the PostgreSQL service.
So I'd be glad if you vote up or accept the answer as it solved your issue, ensuring that others encountering similar errors can benefit from it as well.

But why do I get the error I get and not no response, and why do the backend service start? As I understand healtcheck, when backend depends upon db then it should'nt start if the healthcheck fails.

Thanks for the feedback. I need to see other services definitions (and network if created) in your compose file, and also the error in details you get after running docker compose up --build command.

I'm quite sure the other services have nothing do to with this, running a new compose file with only the db service still gives the same error  test-db-1  | 2024-05-15 05:46:30.860 UTC [139] FATAL:  role " postgres" does not exist. I'm suspecting this might have something to do with the exit codes of pg-isready, as it returns 2 when it can't connect. This is something the docker documentation discourages, https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#healthcheck

This error message says that there’s no user named postgres in the DB. Your error is related to the problem of creating role or user for postgres.
When you only add db service and comment out other services in the compose file, the error occurs because I think the environment variables you send with server (backend service in compose) are commented and PostgreSQL can not fine user account named postgres.
See postgres and server services usage with compose example from docker. https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/develop/

I don't think so, the database is setup independently from the backend. And the error is not that it can't find the role "postgres" but that it can't find the role " postgres" (with a whitespace infront.)
